# How to execute code from another file in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a question about executing dart code from flutter app. So I have two files. The first on contains the build of my app and the second some dart code that is supposed to run in the background. How do I run the code from the second file from the first file?

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide both files please? Normally you import the 2nd file in your 1st one and assign the action that should be run on a certain event (tap of a button) to the onPressed function or similar.